# automount is flooding /var/log/messages with the line "automount[21736]: do_mount_indirect: indirect trigger not valid or already mounted"

Tags: linux, automounting, freeipa

I am facing an issue with automount on a bunch of linux centos hosts.
I see the following line in /var/log/messages to thousands

```
automount[21736]: do_mount_indirect: indirect trigger not valid or already mounted"
```

I enabled debugging on autofs and the logline is now more verbose.

```
Jul 18 14:43:49 hostname automount[128192]: handle_packet: type = 3
Jul 18 14:43:49 hostname automount[128192]: handle_packet_missing_indirect: token 12758048, name <username>, request pid 74868
Jul 18 14:43:49 hostname automount[128192]: do_mount_indirect: indirect trigger not valid or already mounted /home/nfs/<username>
Jul 18 14:43:49 hostname automount[128192]: dev_ioctl_send_ready: token = 12758048
```

These logfiles are filling up my /var/log partition.

I tried to google/chatgpt my problem but no success yet. The only correlation I see at the moment is that I only see these error logs on hosts where containerd is also installed/running.

Content of `/etc/auto.master`

```
[root@hostname ~]# cat /etc/auto.master | grep -v '^#'
/misc   /etc/auto.misc
/net    -hosts
+dir:/etc/auto.master.d
+auto.master
```

The folder `/etc/auto.master.d/` is empty.

Content of `/etc/auto.misc`

```
[root@hostname ~]# cat /etc/auto.misc | grep -v '^#'
cd              -fstype=iso9660,ro,nosuid,nodev :/dev/cdrom
```

Does anybody know how to fix that issue or give me a hint?

We are automounting home folders with freeipa. Works fine on hundreds of hosts except a bunch of hosts. I compared the config files on working and not working hosts. No difference so far.

Comment: 1. Please also add the content of your `/etc/auto.misc`. 2. Since you said it works on hundreds of machines but fails on few of those, compare the configuration between successful and failed hosts. 3. Notice part of the error is `or already mounted`. The error probably also says which area it refers to. Please also add it to your question, and run `df` on this path. 4. Then also run `df` on the same path from a successful machine so you could compare.

Comment: Ty aviro for your hints. Yes it is already mounted. Something is triggering the mount command I have no idea where it is coming from.
Normally it should only mount the home shares if someone is login in with ssh. But some of these folders are mounted without a user interaction.

Comment: You mentioned `containerd`, are any of those containers mounting any of your `autofs` mounts from the host?  You also mentioned that your `autofs` is configured through FreeIPA, that would likely mean there are no used local configuration files for `autofs` on the hosts as they would be delivered by FreeIPA.